# Very basic doubt about Itô's lemma

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

While trying obtain the dynamics of $X_t = \exp( \int_t ^T \phi_s ds)$, where $\phi$ is an Ito process following
$$ d\phi_t = \mu dt+ \sigma dW_t \ ,$$
I had some doubt concerning the application of Itô's lemma.

If $g_T(t,x) := \int_t ^T x(s) ds$ which is a functional of $x$ depending of $t$ and of the parameter $T$, then $X_t = f_T(t,\phi) :=\exp(g_T(t,\phi))$, so Itô's lemma gives us that 
$$dX_t =df_T(t,\phi) = (\partial_t +\frac{\sigma}{2}\partial_{xx}^2) f_T(t,\phi) dt +\partial_x f_T(t,\phi) dW_t$$
My doubt is precisely about the computation of $\partial_x f_T(t,\phi)$. Is it zero or am I making a mistake?

Thus, the dynamic of $X$ must be

$$dX_t =\partial_t  f_T(t,\phi) dt =-\phi_tX_tdt$$

Could someone enlight me please?

Comment: Should it be $X_T=\exp{(\int_t^T\phi_s ds)}$ or does the process $X$ depends on the lower bound of the integral?

Comment: What's the definition of the dynamic of a stochastic process? What have you tried?

Comment: @n.c.: the second answer;

Comment: @saz: The dynamic of a stochastic process means de EDS it satisfies. Here in the sens of an Ito's process,ie, an EDS in terms of the brownian motion like $\phi$.

Comment: @Paul Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: Very basic question: what did you try? (And how come the formatting of this question is so far from being acceptable, being your question #27 on the site?)

Comment: You say, you have a basic doubt, but you didn't specify what do you doubt about.

Comment: @Did: Please see my edits. I'm sorry for the short question, I was rushed

Comment: @Ilya:Please see my edits.

Comment: Did you check that X is a diffusion?

Comment: @Did: How? I guess I didn't understand your question.

Comment: If $\phi$ is a diffusion and $dX_t=\sigma(X_t,\phi_t)dW_t+b(X_t,\phi_t)dt$, then $X$ is a diffusion. But if your $X$ is not a diffusion, to try to describe it as one is doomed. Here, a problem is that $X_t$ is not adapted.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The point is that Ito Lemma applies to the situation where you have a function of an Ito process, rather than a functional. E.g. you can apply it in case $h(\phi_t)$, but you don't apply Ito Lemma to compute the differential of $\int_0^t\phi_s\mathrm ds$. In the latter case you rather have
$$
  \mathrm d\left(\int_0^t\phi_s\mathrm ds\right) = \phi_t\mathrm dt.
$$
Similarly, for any continuous function $\psi \in C([0,\infty))$ you have that 
$$
  g(t):=\int_t^T\psi(s)\mathrm ds \in C^1([0,\infty))
$$
and thus $f(t):=\exp(g(t))$ belongs to this class as well. As a result,
$$
  \mathrm df(t) = f'_t(t)\mathrm dt = f(t)g'_t(t)\mathrm dt = -f(t)\psi(t)\mathrm dt.
$$